# How to create Different screen size Layouts in android studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android studio 1.4.I Trying t create my Layout XML for supporting different screen sizes but i don't how to create all the stuff in android studio ,i tried it but it showing small screen size in my immlator please any one help me how to create it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Small size means? Try placing the images in respective folders.

Answer (score 0):

try Percent Support Library for support all screen size. If you want read about Percent Support Library please check [link1](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/percent/package-summary.html) and [link2](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#percent). Add dependencies in your project.

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
}`

**edit 26th March 2018**
Now you can create responsive layout for every size of device just using **[constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)** in your xml design.
here is the some tutorial example for constraint layout
[codelabe tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#0) and [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z53Ed0ddxgM)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following  image for Multiple Screens

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your should used -

layout-large,
layout-small,
layout,
layout-extralarge

and made separate layout for it